# google calendar problem on iPhone

Tags: iphone

When I enter an event on the iPhone Google calendar, it does not show up in the monthly view on the iPhone.  It does appear in the weekly and daily views on the iPhone.  It also appears in all views, including monthly, when synced to my MAC Air computer.  I have tried re-entering the event, but all I get is a spinning wheel on the monthly view.

Comment: Does calendar.google.com show it?

Comment: This might be a timing compatibility issue between servers. It's happened to me before. I gave it a day and it fixed itself.

Comment: Problem solved.